# Propositions equivalent to the completeness of the real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, reverse-math, lo.logic

Can anyone point me to a reasonably comprehensive article (or book chapter) explaining which basic theorems of calculus are equivalent to the completeness axiom of the reals and which ones aren't?

Here "equivalent" means equivalent relative to a base system that includes all the ordered field axioms, plus naïve set theory, plus (optionally) the Peano axioms (which one probably needs if one wants to use the natural numbers as an index-set, e.g. in the Nested Intervals Property).

At first I thought reverse mathematics would be the place to look, but a little bit of poking around now leads me to think that reverse mathematics in the usual sense deals with more arcane issues, with base systems that are at once weaker and stronger than what I have in mind: Konig's infinity lemma isn't provable in all of them, but the Intermediate Value Theorem is.

(Stephen Simpson, in his Wikipedia article http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics, writes:
"... RCA0 is sufficient to prove a number of classical theorems which, therefore, require only minimal logical strength.  These theorems are, in a sense, below the reach of the reverse mathematics enterprise because they are already provable in the base system. The classical theorems provable in RCA0 include: ... Basic properties of the real numbers (the real numbers are an Archimedean ordered field; any nested sequence of closed intervals whose lengths tend to zero has a single point in its intersection; the real numbers are not countable). ... The intermediate value theorem on continuous real functions.".)

So, reverse mathematics may not be the place to turn for answers to questions like "Is the completeness of the reals equivalent to the Mean Value Theorem?" (answer: yes); but I'm sure someone has considered such questions systematically. Perhaps somebody wrote a beautiful Monthly article a few decades ago that explained things so clearly as to make the whole matter seem trivial, with the result that the article was forgotten? :-)

Comment: My omission of the Archimedean axiom from the base theory was intentional. Indeed, one way to show that various theorems of calculus do NOT imply completeness is to show that they are satisfied by non-Archimedean totally ordered fields.

Comment: This reference might help:

http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~tom/mathfiles/rolle_Illinois.pdf

Of course you can also look for more recent articles that cite it.



Comment: T. W. Körner, *A Companion to Analysis* discusses some of this.

Comment: Maybe I should ask a couple of concrete mathematical questions as illustrations of the sort of things I'd like to know:

Can the completeness of the reals be derived from the fact that every contraction map has a unique fixed point?

Can the completeness of the reals be derived from the fact that every continuous function has an antiderivative?

(I suspect that non-Archimedean fields provide a counterexample to the latter, but I don't know enough about analysis in non-Archimedean fields to be sure.)

Comment: This question is difficult to answer because it is too vague. First, there are two different axioms of completeness for the reals: Cauchy completeness and Dedekind completeness. I suspect you mean the latter, but this is not clear from the question. Second, the base theory you describe is unclear. What kind of comprehension axioms does your "naïve set-theory" comprise? Are the (optional!) natural numbers distinguished elements of the field or are they a separate sort? How are functions coded in this theory?

Comment: I would suggest we assume countable choice here so that Cauchy completeness (every Cauchy sequence has a limit) and Dedekid completeness (an inhabited bounded set has a supremum) coincide. The "naive set" business is about doing things "directly", rather than some encoding in second-order arithmetic, I think.

Comment: I don't think countable choice, or any other set-theoretic axiom, is going to let you prove that Cauchy completeness and Dedekind completeness coincide, in the absence of the Archimedean Property; for there are non-Archimedean ordered fields (such as the field of rational functions "ordered at infinity") that are Cauchy complete but not Dedekind complete. Or am I missing something here, Andrej?

Comment: François is correct in surmising that when I wrote "completeness" I meant "Dedekind completeness".  As for what base theory I am presupposing, François answered this question very convincingly in the thread http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71344/truth-vs-provability-for-ordered-fields : it's second-order logic with standard semantics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the article I was looking for doesn't seem to exist, I decided to write one myself; the current draft can be found at http://jamespropp.org/reverse.pdf .

Comments are welcome!

Comment: Very interesting! What would be wonderful is a chart with arrows giving the implications between the various properties. 

Comment: I am having trouble in understand the exact theory that you are working in. It seems to me like a modification of the theory RCF (the theory of real closed fields which is complete for the first order properties of real numbers in the language of ordered fields), it would be nice to state the exact language and axioms of the theory in one place.

Comment: You may also want to check the first volume of "Constructivism in Mathematics" by van Dalen and Troelstra where they develop a theory for elementary analysis and discuss the equivalence/non-equivalence of various analytical principles and definition (constructively).

Comment: I'll look into van Dalen Troelstra; thanks for the reference.  Meanwhile, can you give me more information about the completeness of the theory RCF?  This might resolve the issue about provability that I didn't know how to address at the bottom of page 2 and the top of page 3.

Comment: The language of RCF is the language of ordered rings. The axioms are the axioms for an ordered field plus axioms stating that every polynomial of odd degree has a root (IIRC). The theory is complete in the sense that for any true first order sentence in this language, either RCF proves it or RCF proves its negation. You can find more about RCF in model theory books like David Marker's. 

Comment: On second thought, RCF isn't going to be so relevant to my paper, since the axiom that every polynomial of odd degree has a root doesn't play a role and isn't even mentioned.

Comment: Don't know if RCF is related to your paper, but just as a note, RCF has equivalent formulations without existence of roots for polynomials of odd degree (c.f. Marker).

Comment: btw, the language and axioms of the theory are still not clear to me, but if it is second order version of theory of ordered fields with the standard semantics for the second ordered part then I would guess that the theory will be equivalent (bi-interpretable) to full second-order arithmetic (since natural numbers are definable in the ordered fields using second-order quantification).

Comment: @James, very interesting article! (The references are missing though.) BTW, last time I taught introductory real analysis I did use the approach of identifying the theorems that were equivalent to completeness. And like you I started with the cut property as the defining axiom! But that was before I read your article...

Comment: Very nice and very useful paper! Especially the fact, that bounded value property doesn't imply completeness... And this simple trick that both the set of all upper bounds B and its complement A must be open which allows us to define a continuous function as -1 on A and 1 on B works great! I was just thinking over these issues and decided to find out if somebody has done it before, I guess you were the first one!? Really looks strange, that no one payed attention to this before 2011...

Comment: I usually give my students a proof that The Convergence of Cauchy Sequences (11), and The Nested Interval Property (18) imply LUB property and therefore are equivalent to completeness. There I use dichotomy and construct a set of nested intervals with  $|I_n|=\frac{b-a}{2^n}$, and their intersection is the LUB of our bounded nonempty set. Now I see, that in fact I use The Archimedean Property to prove that $\frac{1}{2^n} \to 0$! So this proof holds only for Archimedean fields...

Comment: On page 13 of your [RAiR](http://faculty.uml.edu/jpropp/reverse.pdf) paper, I'm pretty sure you'll need an ordinal with uncountable [cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality), which $\omega_1$ does not provably-in-ZF have. $\;$

Comment: I don't understand the role of the axiom of choice in the theory of ordinals deeply enough to see what the problem is, but let me sidestep my ignorance and ask, what's an example of an ordinal that can be shown in ZF to have uncountable cofinality?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/33032/5810 ​ ​

Comment: If I'm interpreting that thread correctly, then one can't use ZF to prove the existence of an ordinal with uncountable cofinality. (If this is wrong, please let me know!)

Comment: That's right. ​ ​

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: I noticed that I misunderstood the question after posting the answer, so this is not a answer to the question. I am leaving it here just in case it might be interesting to others.

---

This is studied in bounded reverse math by people like [Fernando Ferreira](http://www.ciul.ul.pt/~ferferr/index_english.html) and colleagues.

The base theory BTFA [Fer'94] is a two sorted theory version of Sam Buss's bounded arithmetic theory $S^1_2(\alpha)$ [Bus85, ch. 9] plus bounded collection/replacement for $\Sigma^b_\infty $ formulas ($B\Sigma^b_\infty$) plus a form of comprehension axiom for $\Delta_1$ sets ($\nabla^b_1CA$):

$$\forall x (\forall z \ \varphi(x,z) \leftrightarrow \exists y \ \psi(x,y)) \Rightarrow \exists Z \ \forall x \ (x \in Z \leftrightarrow \exists y \ \psi(x,y))$$

where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are respectively $\Pi^b_1$ and $\Sigma^b_1$ formulas. This is a modification of Simpson's axiom in his book [Sim'09]. Because of its special form the first order part is conservative over $S^1_2$ and is incapable of using the full power of comprehension for $\Delta_1$ sets. On the other hand, the second order part of the smallest model of the theory is $\Delta_1$ sets.

In [FF'02, thm. 4], a version of the Intermediate Value Theorem is proven in BTFA. Some caution is needed here in formalizing the IVT. Also the proof is not constructive (either there is a rational number which is the root of the function or we can continue a process getting arbitrary close to a root. Deciding that a given rational number is not a root of the function is not decidable and this is required since we need to stop the process of dividing the current interval into two halves if we reach a root, i.e. we need this assumption so we have $f(m)<0 \ \lor \ f(m)>0$ where $m$ is the rational mid-point of the current interval). As far as I remember WKL is not provable in BTFA. See also [FF'05] and [FF'08].

---

References:

1. Fernando Ferreira, "[A feasible theory for analysis](http://www.ciul.ul.pt/~ferferr/feasible.pdf)", The Journal of Symbolic Logic 59, 1001-1011, 1994.
2. António Fernandes and Fernando Ferreira, "[Groundwork for weak analysis](http://www.ciul.ul.pt/~ferferr/groundwork.pdf)", The Journal of Symbolic Logic 67, pp. 557-578, 2002.
3. António Fernandes and Fernando Ferreira, "[Basic applications of weak König's lemma in feasible analysis](http://www.ciul.ul.pt/~ferferr/basic.pdf)", in "Reverse Mathematics 2001", edited by Stephen Simpson. Lecture Notes on Logic (Association for Symbolic Logic), vol. 21, pp. 175-188 (A K Peters, 2005).
4. Fernando Ferreira and Gilda Ferreira, "[The Riemann integral in weak systems of analysis](http://www.ciul.ul.pt/~ferferr/riemann_ff.pdf)", Journal of Universal Computer Science, 14, no. 6, pp. 908-937 (2008).
5. Samuel R. Buss, "[Bounded Arithmetic](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/BAthesis)", Bibliopolis, Revision of 1985 Ph.D. thesis.
6. Stephen G. Simpson, "[Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic](http://www.math.psu.edu/simpson/sosoa/)", Second Edition, Perspectives in Logic, Association for Symbolic Logic, Cambridge University Press, 2009.

Comment: This is a good answer, Kaveh. You should undelete it. There is also interesting work of Phuong Nguyen and Stephen Cook in this area that might be useful.

Comment: I deleted my answer since these theories still satisfy "base systems that are at once weaker and stronger than what I have in mind: Konig's infinity lemma isn't provable in all of them, but the Intermediate Value Theorem is."