# Is there a nice characterisation of topoi with nice meta-logical properties?

Tags: topos-theory, ct.category-theory, lo.logic

First-order order classical logic with standard semantics has a proof theory: it is complete, sound and effective.

In higher order logic with standard semantics  one cannot obtain a proof theory - it cannot be simulateously complete, sound and effective.

Now, the internal language of a topos is higher order typed intuitionistic logic. Presumably like higher order classical logic it won't have nice meta-logical properties either.

Is there a nice characterisation for toposes with these nice properties for its internal language?

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand what you mean by completeness and soundness in this context. Maybe you should clarify your thought ?

For classical logic (or higher order logic) these properties make sense because the logic is defined by a set of rules and axiome and you can indeed show that "something is true if and only if it is provable" but for the internal logic of a precise topos $T$ there is no such set (or at least not a canonical one ! )



Comment: I am unsure how to interpret "effectivity". How can completeness be a problem for ineffective logics?

Comment: I agree that completeness and effectivity fail for classical higher-order logics, but why do you say that soundness fails?  If one chooses axioms and rules of inference in a reasonable way, soundness should hold.

Comment: I tihnk he means the combination soudness+completeness+effectivness with respect to set-theoretic semantics.

Comment: I think Andrej is correct. The OP is probably referring to what I described in this earlier answer - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71344/truth-vs-provability-for-ordered-fields/71353#71353

Comment: @Simon Henry: I'm not entirely sure myself - mathematical logic & topos theory are both new areas to me. Andrej Bauers comment I think is the correct one as to what I was trying to suggest, and his answer has helped a lot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The undesirable properties of higher-order logic are created by an insufficient notion of model. That is, we cannot have all three, soundness, completeness and effectivness (decidability of proof checking), if we insist that formulas be interpreted in the "standard" set-theoretic way. Henkin semantics does not suffer from this defficiency.

What this says is *not* that something is wrong with higher-order logic, but that something is wrong with those who refuse to look at semantic models, even when they are right in front of their faces, because these models are "unintended", "philosophically unacceptable", "not what mathematicians think", etc. This phenomenon of refusing to accept new interpretations of old theories is quite persistent, and always very harmful. Didn't someone stall progress in noneuclidean geometry because it was unthinkable that there would be strange new models? Aren't imaginary numbers so called because they were unthinkable and did not "really exist"? Doesn't higher-order classical logic suffer because it is being denied its natural notion of models on the grounds that they are non-standard?

The natural notion of model for intuitionistic higher-order logic (IHOL) is that of a topos. With respect to topos semantics, it is a standard result that IHOL enjoys soundness, completeness and effectivness.

We may specialize this standard fact to classical higher-order logic (CHOL). The result then is that, with respect to Boolean topos semantics, CHOL enjoys soundness, completeness and effectivness. From here on, we may prove various technical theorems which allow us to cut down on the class of Boolean toposes which is stil sufficient for completeness. And then it is not much of a surprise that we cannot cut down just to a single topos known as classical sets, which is called "Paradise" by its prisioners.

Comment: I think you are a bit too polemic here. Studying higher order logic gets _interesting_ by enforcing standard semantics, there is nothing wrong about such research. Henkin semantics make HOL very similar to FOL and it loses its genuine interesting properties (which include a higher degree of undecidability, non-compactness, and special properties of the universal, existential and monadic second-order-fragments), although I agree with you that such philosophical arguments for standard models in the context of foundations as mentioned by you are very dubious.

Comment: Indeed. There is nothing higher-order about the logic of Henkin semantics, it is just multi-sorted first-order logic with a light touch of syntactic sugar, and it would save unnecessary confusion if people called it as such.

Comment: Is it ok to copy this answer over to math.stackexchange where I first asked this question and got no answers? With due acknowledgement of course.

Comment: @TheUser: I think Andrej is being polemical to allow for a new perspective. He specifically says he doesn't dismiss HOL - "What this says is not that something is wrong with higher-order logic, but that something is wrong with those who refuse to look at semantic models"

Comment: @Mozibur I think it is wrong to call standard models “insufficient” and the properties of HOL with standard semantics “undesirable”. These special phenomena are what most research in HOL is about, they can be called an essence of HOL. Of course it is good to have in mind that we could choose different semantics and in some contexts considering such models is certainly insightful. But the point of higher-order logic is definitely _not_ reflected by Henkin semantics or any recursively enumerable theory.

Comment: @TheUser: I think he's aiming his polemic to people who say these models are "unintended", "philosophically unacceptable", "not what mathematicians think". Its not aimed at people, like you, who accept that its possible to have new insights by considering a different class of models. Of course his polemic might have the unintended consequence of abandoning research in HOL the way you describe - but I  expect thats it is highly unlikely. Sure, Henkin semantics is not *everything* about HOL, but it is *something* - and Topos theory places it in a natural context.

Comment: @TheUser: Although I think it is probably a fair characterization that this response is polemical, the points being made seem more general than just Henkin semantics (and it seems to me that Andrej is not making his claim only about them).  The point stands that there are other ways to provide interpretations that avoid metalogical difficulties, beyond just that provided by Henkin semantics.  For example, Artemov's LP appears to be another direction for providing a higher-order semantics with these desirable properties.

Comment: I do not know LP, it is probably quite interesting. Let me just clarify that my objection also does not only apply to the case of Henkin semantics: A fundamental motivation of higher-order logic is the possibility to define the natural numbers and the real numbers up to isomorphism (as given by the set theory used as an underlying foundation). If you want to preserve this, you necessarily get non-compactness and a higher degree of uncomputability (and the theory of such degrees is in fact deeply connected with the theory of HOL).

Comment: @TheUser: What do you mean by defining the natural numbers upto isomorphism? Is this connected to the lack of categoricity in first order logic, but obtained in second order logics?

Comment: @User: What do you mean by "these special phenomena are what most research in HOL is about"?

Comment: I am pretty sure questions are not supposed to be (too) polemical. But i also the answers must not be polemical, then we might as well pack our suitcases and go home. I am glad @The User is presenting the opposite view. I am referring to more than just Henkin semantics, of course (that is just the first historical step).

Comment: @TheUser: the standard models are insufficient for a very simple reason, namely that they do not give completeness. Yes, you can insist on staring just as standard models, but in my experience lack of completeness indicates one of two things: you forgot an axiom, or you forgot some models. Since we like effectivness, in the case of CHOL it has to be the latter.

Comment: The fact that more general semantics makes HOL look more like first-order logic is *good*, not *bad*! It gives standard meta-theoretic properties, it allows us to prove things, it gives a wealth of models, etc. I really do not understand the fascination with studying only a very specific situation in HOL, but that must be because I am not a Platonist.

Comment: But to steer away from philohophy, here is a meta-technical remark. Just like it is advantageous to know about topological spaces even if one is doing just real analysis and so technically $\mathbb{R}^n$ suffices, so it is better to view standard HOL semantics as just a special case of general semantics (topos-theoretic). Then one can wield all sorts of tools, concepts and techniques to study *standard* semantics, not to mention one enjoys completeness and effectiveness as well.

Comment: @Mozibur You can give a second-order formula such that all models are isomorphic to the natural numbers. In first-order logic that is obviously not possible because of completeness/compactness/Löwenheim-Skolem.
@Andrej I am not a Platonist and in fact I think that HOL with standard semantics is irrelevant for foundations/philosophy of mathematics.
@François I think it was wrong to say “most”, however, _model theory_ of second-order logic gets interesting by enforcing standard semantics. Model theory of Henkin semantics is just FO model theory (which is of course more fruitful, but not HOL).

Comment: @Andrej Be as polemical as you want to be. The freedom to give polemical answers is certainly fruitful.

Comment: We seem to be in agreement.